# AngularJS/UI-Router change state from select/option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have a SPA using AngularJS/UI-Router and I have a section where I need to change states from a select/option. I originally had links in an `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li data-ng-repeat="course in courses">
        <a data-ui-sref=".materials({ courseCode:course.CourseCode })">{{course.Title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The issue is that I am going to have upwards of 50 different courses to choose from, so I want to put them into a select/option setup something like this:

```
<select style="padding:3px 1px; width:100%;" data-ng-model="placeholder" data-ng-options="course.Title for course in courses track by course.CourseCode"></select>
```

Now, I know I can change the scope with the above by setting up an `ng-repeat` and just using that `ng-model="placeholder"`, but I need the ability to change states from that select/option. Basically, I have a check that occurs on state change that will either deny or allow access based on a permissions check. If I can do the permissions check from this state, I am more than open to that as an option, but it seemed easier to switch states and do the check on that.

As always, thank you in advance!

**Edit**: So I looked some more into this and found that I might be able to do something with `ng-switch` and UI-Router's `$state.go`. Here is what I have come up with so far:

The controller:

```
.controller('CoursesTrackCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $log, $state) {
    $scope.changeState = function (course) {
        $state.go('.materials({ courseCode:course.CourseCode })');
    }
});
```

The state with the select:

```
<select style="padding:3px 1px; width:100%;" data-ng-model="course" data-ng-options="course.Title for course in courses" data-ng-change="changeState(course)">
    <option value="">-- Select a Course --</option>
</select>
```

I am getting an `undefined is not a function` when I change the option in the select menu. I can get an alert to pop and pass through pieces of the courses so I know that course is being passed through the scope just fine. I made sure that `$state` had been added to the controller, but it seems like `$state.go` isn't going anywhere and I am still not even sure if that would be the correct syntax to actually pass through `$stateParams` like I would with a normal `ui-sref`.

**Solution**:

With the help of `David Spence`, I was able to solve the error I was having. I was both injecting `$state` into the controller and using it as a parameter so it was throwing an error. Thank you!

As for the solution, this was the final section of code for the controller:

```
.controller('CoursesTrackCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $log, $state) {
    $scope.changeState = function (course) {
        $state.go('courses.track.materials', { courseCode: course.CourseCode });
    }
});
```

The big change here was the syntax for `$state.go`, which needed to resolve the full path of the state (`courses.track.materials` vs. just `.materials`) and the syntax for the parameters differed from the normal `ui-sref` syntax so it had to be setup as a `{ parameter : value }`.

And for the state itself:

```
<select style="padding:3px 1px; width:100%;" data-ng-model="course" data-ng-options="course.Title for course in courses" data-ng-change="changeState(course)">
    <option value="">-- Select a Course --</option>
</select>
```

This had been mostly unchanged, but the big thing was to ensure that `course` was being passed through the scope.

Hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that is wrong is that `$state` is being passed as a parameter the `changeState` method instead of being injected into the controller. See example below without any errors. Just check the state name is correct you are changing to. Looks a bit odd the way it starts with a dot...

```
function BasicController($scope) {

    $scope.changeState = function(course) {
        console.log(course.Title);
        // todo: transition!
    }

    $scope.courses = [{
        Title: 'maths'
    }, {
        Title: 'science'
    }];

}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spencerooni/c48gX/)</kbd>

Comment: The syntax for `state.go` is different that if you're using `ui-sref` on an anchor. Instead, the first parameter is the state name and the second are the parameters. In your case, something like: `$state.go('.materials', { courseCode: course.CourseCode });`. Check [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) and does your state name really begin with a dot?

Comment: You're the man. I just posted a full answer above, but I will credit you since that is exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you for your help!